# Programa que mostra a localização em um fila

Tags: python

Esse programa mostrará a localização de uma pessoa na fila quando digitado o nome, porém, não estou conseguindo.

> Erro:   File "C:/Users/Cleit/PycharmProjects/xxx/xxx.py", line 79, in
>   
>       import Fila ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Fila'

O programa é em Python 3.
 Eu tentei sem importar as classes mas aparecia erro dizendo que 'fila' não tinha sido definida.
 O metodo 'procurar' aparentemente não esta recebendo o dado de 'pessoaprocurada'.
 Comecei a aprender fila essa semana na faculdade não sei muito sobre.

```
class Pessoa:
    nome = ""
    idade = 0
    sexo = ""
    peso = 0
    proxima = None


class Fila:
    inicio = None
    final = None


def inserir(fila, pessoa):
    if filaVazia(fila):
        fila.inicio = pessoa
        fila.final = pessoa
    else:
        fila.final.proxima = pessoa
        fila.final = pessoa


def tamanho(fila):
    if (filaVazia(fila) == True):
        return 0
    else:
        contadorFila = 0
        pessoaTmp = fila.inicio
        while pessoaTmp != None:
            contadorFila += 1
            pessoaTmp = pessoaTmp.proxima
        return contadorFila


def filaVazia(fila):
    statusFila = (fila.inicio == None and fila.final == None)
    return statusFila


def imprimir(fila):
    pessoaTmp = fila.inicio
    while pessoaTmp != None:
        print("Nome:", pessoaTmp.nome, ",", "Idade:", pessoaTmp.idade, end="-->" if pessoaTmp.proxima != None else "\n")
        pessoaTmp = pessoaTmp.proxima


def procurar_por_nome(Fila, pessoaprocurada):
    for pessoaprocurada in Fila:
        if Pessoa.nome == pessoaprocurada:
            return Pessoa

    return None


filaEncadeada = Fila()
opcao = 1

while opcao != 0:
    print("1 - Inserir")
    print("2 - Pesquisar elemento")
    print("3 - Verificar se a fila esta vazia")
    print("4 - Tamanho da fila")
    print("5 - Ver fila")
    print("0 - Sair")
    opcao = int(input("Opção: "))

    if opcao == 1:
        nome = (input("Nome: "))
        idade = int(input("Idade: "))
        sexo = input("Sexo: ")
        peso = float(input("Peso: "))
        novaPessoa = Pessoa()
        novaPessoa.nome = nome
        novaPessoa.idade = idade
        novaPessoa.sexo = sexo
        novaPessoa.peso = peso
        inserir(filaEncadeada, novaPessoa)

    if opcao == 2:
        import Fila
        import Pessoa

        pessoaprocurada = input("Pessoa a procurar: ")
        procurar_por_nome(Fila, pessoaprocurada)

    if opcao == 3:
        if (filaVazia(filaEncadeada) == True):
            print(f"Esta fila está vazia")
        else:
            print(f"Esta fila não esta vazia, possui: {tamanho(filaEncadeada)} elemento(s)")

    if opcao == 4:
        print(f"Tamanho Fila: {tamanho(filaEncadeada)}")

    elif opcao == 5:
        imprimir(filaEncadeada)
```

Answer (score 0):

Com relação ao seu problema, está sendo gerado esse erro porque você está tentando importar um módulo chamado `Fila`, módulo que não existe no seu diretório atual.

Encontrei também outros erros no seu código como por exemplo no bloco `if opcao == 2`. Você está passando como parâmetro da função `procurar_por_nome` uma classe e não um objeto. Além disso, dentro da sua função `procurar_por_nome` você definiu a instrução `for pessoa_procurada in Fila` sendo que sua classe `Fila` não tem o método `__iter__` para ser um iterador.

Enfim, existem vários problemas no seu código que devem ser resolvidos, mas se você quiser trabalhar com filas, eu recomendo o módulo `queue` ou então, recomendo criar um objeto de `list` para guardar todas as pessoas. Veja esse exemplo abaixo que eu fiz:

```
class Pessoa(object):
    def __init__(self,nome,sexo,idade,peso):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade
        self.sexo = sexo
        self.peso = peso

    def __repr__(self):
        # Mostra o nome da pessoa ao invés do endereço de memória
        return self.nome


class Fila(object):
    __pessoas = [] # Lista que irá conter todas as pessoas registradas.

    def __iter__(self):
        self.__index = -1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.__index += 1

        if self.__index >= len(self.__pessoas):
            raise StopIteration
        return self.__pessoas[self.__index]

    def __len__(self):
        # Retorna o tamanho da fila.
        return len(self.__pessoas)

    def vazio(self):
        if self.__pessoas:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def inserir(self,pessoa):
        self.__pessoas.append(pessoa)

    def obterPosicao(self,nome):
        i = 0
        for pessoa in self.__pessoas:
            if pessoa.nome == nome:
                return i+1
            i += 1

    def obterPessoa(self,posicao):
        if posicao <= len(self.__pessoa):
            return self.__pessoas[posicao]

    def obterPessoas(self):
        return self.__pessoas

    def deletar(self,posicao):
        if posicao <= len(self.__pessoa):
            self.__pessoas.pop(posicao-1)



opcao = -1
fila = Fila()

while opcao != 0:
    print("\n"*40)
    print("1 - Inserir")
    print("2 - Obter posição de um elemento")
    print("3 - Verificar se a fila está vazia")
    print("4 - Tamanho da fila")
    print("5 - Ver fila")
    print("0 - Sair")

    opcao = input("Opção: ")
    if not opcao.isnumeric(): continue
    opcao = int(opcao)
    print("")

    if opcao == 1:

        nome = input("Nome: ")
        idade = int(input("Idade: "))
        sexo = input("Sexo: ")
        peso = float(input("Peso: "))
        nova_pessoa = Pessoa(nome,sexo,idade,peso)
        fila.inserir(nova_pessoa)
        print("Pessoa inserida com sucesso.")

    if opcao == 2:
        nome = input("Digite o nome: ")
        posicao = fila.obterPosicao(nome)
        if not posicao:
            print("Essa pessoa não existe.")
        else:
            print("Posição:",posicao)

    if opcao == 3:
        if fila.vazio():
            print("Está vazio.")
        else:
            print("Existem elementos na fila.")
    if opcao == 4:
        print("Existem",len(fila),"elementos na fila.")

    if opcao == 5:
        print("Fila:",fila.obterPessoas())
    input("\nAperte ENTER para continuar.")
```

Teste esse código para ver se é o que deseja, estude e veja o que pode melhorar no seu próprio código. Recomendo que estude mais sobre POO (Programação Orientada a Objeto).

Espero ter lhe ajudado =D

Comment: Nossa você é muito bom quero chegar a esse nivel um dia. Vou analisar linha por linha e ver onde falhei. Muito obrigado!!!